# Getting -0200 in DateTime from MySQL/Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'm getting a column whose its type is DateTime and comes from MySQL database.

But I can't get `%H:%M:%S` (it's showing me `00:00:00`) because I guess that something is going wrong here. See:

```
= debug current_user.last_access_at.to_s
```

Output:

> '2014-01-20 11:15:40 -0200'

What is that `-0200` there? And plus, how can I get the time correctly?

*Note that I'm using Ruby On Rails.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your timezone offset.

it means that you have a setting for -2 hours from timezone 0.

for a more useful format you can use [`strftime(format)`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime) instead of `to_s`